# Entity Framework CORE batch processing taking long time

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am passing a few records with Jquery ajax() to a .Net CORE MVC controller to batch update a SQL table.  It then calls `TransactionalDeleteAndInsert()` in a repository to delete then insert the records as shown in the following code.

When done, `_repoContext.SaveChangesAsync()` is executed. The delete/update actions take a few seconds to complete, but when I refresh the screen or navigate to another page, the get method to get the updated list took more than 2 hours.  What am I doing wrong?

```cs
public int BatchInsert(IList<T> entityList)
{
  int inserted = 0;
  foreach(T entity in entityList)
  {
    this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    inserted++;
  }

  return inserted;
}

public int BatchDelete(IList<T> entityList)
{
  int deleted = 0;
  foreach(T entity in entityList)
  {
    this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    deleted++;
  }
  return deleted;
}

public List<int> TransactionalDeleteAndInsert(IList<T> deleteEntityList, IList<T> insertEntityList)
{
  using (var transaction = this.RepositoryContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
  {
    int totalDeleted = this.BatchDelete(deleteEntityList);
    int totalInserted = this.BatchInsert(insertEntityList);
    transaction.Commit();

    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    result.Add(totalDeleted);
    result.Add(totalInserted);

    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Where does this code run and what't the life cycle of `this.RepositoryContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the snippet above there is not `SaveChangesAsync()` or `SaveChanges()` method executed (I take it that you execute it later on).

That means the whole process occurs locally in your context/memory **only**.

***Transactions***

The fact that BatchDelete() and BatchInsert() methods are wrapped in a transaction does not make a difference because these operations occur in your context, which will probably be recreated in your next request (given that it's lifetime is scoped).

The transaction would make more sense if your code was like this

```
  using (var transaction = this.RepositoryContext.Database.BeginTransaction())
  {
    int totalDeleted = this.BatchDelete(deleteEntityList);
    this.SaveChanges();
    int totalInserted = this.BatchInsert(insertEntityList);
    this.SaveChanges();
    transaction.Commit();

    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    result.Add(totalDeleted);
    result.Add(totalInserted);

    return result;
  }
```

So if for any reason your second db operation would fail the first one would rollback too. (I am aware that this example would not make sense in your case, you could simply execute `SaveChanges()` method at the end of your `TransactionalDeleteAndInsert()` method and you you could avoid any unwanted data saved in your db in case insert fails)

***Slow db operations***

That could be due to many reasons. It could be a slow sql server, very big tables, or long add/remove lists. This is the reason that when you refresh it takes long, because by refreshing you query again your database while it is already under heavy pressure.